# cs-cart и bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap4

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли подключить bootstrap 4 к cs-cart. Установленая trial версия (пока). В ней используется 2-й bootstrap, не хотелось бы иметь с ним ничего общего.
Интересует не просто подключение файла, а чтобы cs-cart понимал его и в разделе макеты добавлял нужные классы

Comment: Есть тема бутстрап, на github, но вроде её не поддерживают и не обновляют, можно взять ща основу, но очень много на 4.10.* допиливать.

Comment: Ссылка на репозиторий была бы очень уместна в ответе, раз вы на гитхаб ссылаетесь.

Comment: Если есть ссылка, или помните название темы, напишите пожалуйста